# How to echo sentences using a bot command [discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'd like some help here, When i do the normal echo command that I use, words/sentence that have spaces wont send the echo, but with single words, It will send.

```
@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.message.author.id in []:
        await ctx.send (*args)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since `*args` provides a tuple with an entry for each word after the command, you might want to consider using [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Also the space after the `send` and before the `(*args)` is a typo. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The def should be like this, make sure to check [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters)

```py
@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx, *,args):
    if ctx.message.author.id in []:
        await ctx.send(args)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")
```